# removeFromSuperview doesn't remove the view

Tags: ios7

I have a little registration "dialog", just a view with two buttons, that I invoke using...

```
self.registerController = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"mainStoryboard" identifier:@"registerVC"];
[self.window addSubview:self.registerController.view];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:self.registerController.view];
```

When this code is called, the view appears as one would expect. When the user clicks one of the buttons, it calls:

```
[self.registerController.view removeFromSuperview];
self.registerController = nil;
```

But the view does not disappear. The rest of the app keeps running fine, but the "dialog" is still there in front of everything. So when you try to dismiss it, by clicking the Cancel button, it send that message to the nil instance and the app crashes.

I suspect this is something trivially obvious, but I'm missing it, as always.

Comment: add this line after "addSubview" and before "removeFromSuperview": "`NSLog(@"registerController view is %p and superview is %p", self.registerController.view, [self.registerController.view superview]);`".  See if they are the same both times the line is called.

Comment: 2014-05-05 07:45:33.977 MARL[42133:60b] registerController view is 0xc849df0 and superview is 0xc8351a0
    2014-05-05 07:45:37.960 MARL[42133:60b] registerController view is 0x1664cf70 and superview is 0xc8351a0

Comment: Ahhh, thank you Michael! The routine was being called twice, for some reason. Two views, identical in size and shape.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's post (above) found the problem, but there's a bit of mystery remaining.

Our app requires you to, eventually register an email address. When you first run the app it puts up the dialog asking you to do so. This was handled by a call in applicationDidBecomeActive.

For whatever reason, applicationDidBecomeActive was being called twice. Therefore there were two copies of the dialog up on the screen. The buttons were working fine on one of them :-)

But why is applicationDidBecomeActive getting called twice? Is this expect?